Веб приложение для загрузки и скачивания файлов
Всем привет! Нужна ваша помощь! Я написал веб-приложения для хранения файлов, с возможностью скачать загруженные файлы. Что-то вроде диска.
Клиент на react, бэк на Asp .Net, сами файлы хранятся в S3 Minio. Но у меня возникла загвоздка со скачиванием файлов. Когда нажимаю на кнопку скачать на клиенте, то происходит ожидание, пока файл будет полностью скачан с хранилища и только потом уже как скачанный сразу передается клиенту через загрузчик браузера. Если файл много весит, то приходится долго ждать, когда он отобразиться в загрузчике.
Возникает вопрос, можно ли сделать так, что бы файл загружался именно в браузере, т.е. после нажатия на кнопку скачать, файл сразу отображался в загрузках в браузере.
Помогите, пожалуйста советом или примером!

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Добавить LongPulling на клиента, чтобы он постоянно опрашивал сервер - "Как там мой файл поживает?". Ну, либо сделать сокет. Тут уже на ваше усмотрение
